# tab alignment issue - not centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

The spacing for the tab is not consistent and this happens in all the browser (Chrome, Firefox & IE). I have two links that are similar. My aim is to have both of them centered.

http://cimbth-pub-uat.mirum-apac.com/content/cimbconsumerthai/en/personal/support/help-and-support/tools/personal-loan-calculator.html [image: 1]

and
http://cimbth-pub-uat.mirum-apac.com/content/cimbconsumerthai/th/personal/support/help-and-support/tools/personal-loan-calculator.html [image: 2]

Was wondering how can I center both tab?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post your css of the tabs

Comment: put them in a table or set width for them

Comment: looks like the browser has issues with calculating the width of non-western text - have you tried a different font family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

set the width of each list item to 50% so your list items are equal in width,the text will then be centered in each

```
.shared-nav .tab-nav li {
    width: 50%;
}
```